# ¿A que se debe este error en Ajax?

Tags: mysql, ajax, datatables

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con ajax pero me sale este error y no se por que ocurre al momento de añadirle una imagen a mi ajax

Answer (score 1):

por lo que muestras en tu imagen obtengo lo siguiente:

1.- No es AJAX es un archivo con estructura JSON
2.- En la línea 6, si ya no vas a meter otra clave->valor ya no debería tener una coma ya que de tenerla es como si le indicaras que este listo para recibir otra pareja de valores.

Otro detalle que deberías revisar es ¿para qué son esos número 1 de las lineas 2, 7, 9, 14?; la estructura de json no va con esos valores por fuera

Saludos, lo anterior es con base en lo que puedo leer de tu archivo

Te muestro un ejemplo de como debería quedar estructurado:

```
[{
        "objetivos": 9,
        "datos": "valor1",
        "content": "contenido1"
    },
    {
        "objetivos": 19,
        "datos": "valor2",
        "content": "contenido2"
    },
    {
        "objetivos": 29,
        "datos": "valor3",
        "content": "contenido3"
    }
]
```

Comment: saludos, si te resulta útil agradecería la marques como la respuesta a tu cuestionamiento Saludos cordiales